# need vba code to delete all the code after executing all the code

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I need a vba code in Excel 2007 which will remove all the vba code after executing all the function. I am drawing an example here:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'Runs a macro 10 seconds after Excel is opened
Call SaveBook
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:9"), "ThisWorkbook.SaveBook"
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "ThisWorkbook.Delete"
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:11"), "ThisWorkbook.Main"
End Sub


 Sub SaveBook()
ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub


Sub delete()
Dim NM As String
Dim CTS As Integer
Dim CNT2 As Integer
Dim CNT3 As Integer
CNT3 = 1
CNT2 = 1
CTS = Sheets.Count
Do Until CNT2 = CTS + 1
NM = Sheets(CNT3).Name
If Name = "Report" Then
Range("A1").Select
CNT3 = CNT3 + 1
Else
Sheets(NM).Select
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If
CNT2 = CNT2 + 1
Loop
    End Sub
Sub Main()
    RemoveCodeFrom "Sheet3"
End Sub

Private Sub RemoveLinesFrom(vbCompName As String)
    Dim vbProj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim vbComp As VBIDE.VBComponent

    Set vbProj = ThisWorkbook.VBProject

    For Each vbComp In vbProj.VBComponents
        If StrComp(vbComp.Name, vbCompName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
            Set CodeMod = vbComp.CodeModule
            With CodeMod
                .DeleteLines 1, .CountOfLines
            End With
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Here, every thing is fine but what I need that at 11 seconds all the vba code will be erased. Is it possible. Please help me. I need the code for security purpose of my file. I want to protect unwanted access to my file.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to save macro-free, use **.xlsx** format rather than **.xlsm** format:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim s As String
    s = Replace(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, "xlsm", "xlsx")
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=s, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    Application.Quit
End Sub
```